# PHP search with mySQL program error

Tags: php, mysql, search, syntax-error

So I am trying to create a search feature in php using mySQL and went through an syntax-error which Ok so I have NO IDEA where fixed it came from, to be more specific the error says a

> "**syntax error**, unexpected 'if'"

and it comes from if ($resault->num_rows > 0) . Can someone explain to me where I went wrong works and/or a possible way to solve this? after reading your answers I changed some of my parameters because I realized you were right about my code.I still don't know what the error was about.

```
<?php
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  @die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_GET["P"])) {
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
  $resault = $conn->query("SELECT title,field_paint_efficeincy__value FROM node_revision, field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_ WHERE title LIKE '$_GET[P]%'");
  echo $resault->num_rows;


  if ($resault->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {
    echo $row['*'] . "<br />";
  }
}
$conn->close();
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get">
  PARAMETER: <input type="text" name="P" value="" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Υπολογισμός" name="sub">
</form>
```

**FIXED**

Ok so I fixed it and it works and after reading your answers I changed some of my parameters because I realized you were right about my code.I still don't know what the error was about.

Comment: You'd help yourself by using decent indentation. Far easier to spot problems with properly indented code.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {
```

To

```
while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc()) {
```

For more info, click [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

**Explanation:**

As, you commented on @**spirytusrektus** Answer's: *"I made the whole line a comment, still the same mistake."*

So, according to me. You did:

```
if ($resault->num_rows > 0) {
  //while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {
    echo $row['*'] . "<br />";
  }
}
```

So, you commented `While loop` but not commented `closing braces` of while loop. That's why same error coming "

> "syntax error, unexpected 'if'"

So, if you really want to test it. Comment both a) `while loop;` and, b) `closing braces` `}` of while loop.

Like,

```
if ($resault->num_rows > 0) {
  //while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {
    echo $row['*'] . "<br />";
  //}
}
```

**But**, you no need to do that.

Just, add `())` in `while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {`

like

`while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: It's not that, because that group of lines is a copy paste from another code and I just forgot to paste those.Either way it's causing an error in a line that doesn't exist which means that the error comes from one of the previous lines, but I can't find which one.

Comment: As Far I See, No Line Is Having Error Except The Line Detected in `fetch_assoc()`. @GeorgeNostradamos

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc {
```

You're missing a `() )` here. As Utkanos commented, decent indentation will help you detect your typing errors.

**UPDATE:**

```
<?
$conn = @new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    @die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ( isset($_GET["P"] ) ) {
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    $resault = $conn->query("SELECT title,field_paint_efficeincy__value FROM node_revision, field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_ WHERE title LIKE '$_GET[P]%'");
    echo $resault->num_rows;


    if ( $resault->num_rows > 0 ) {

        while( $row = $resault->fetch_assoc() ) {

            echo $row['*'] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get">
  PARAMETER: <input type="text" name="P" value="" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="????????µ??" name="sub">
</form>
```

I do not see any syntax error within this code. Try this code block with your connection parameters. If this doesn't help, try rewriting your code.

Comment: I made the whole line a comment, still the same mistake

Comment: @GeorgeNostradamos updated my answer, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$conn>error;` to `print` `error`

```
$conn->query("Your query") or print_r($conn->error);
```

you have error in this line

```
while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc { // forget to use ())
        echo $row['*'] . "<br />";// $rwo['*']; is nothing
      }
```

It should be

```
while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<pre>"; print_r($row) . "<br />";
      }
```

Also in you `sql` you used `$_GET[P]` . It should be `$_GET['P']`;

use this `code`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['P'])){  
//echo $_GET['P'];

$sql = "SELECT title,field_paint_efficeincy__value FROM node_revision, field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_ WHERE title LIKE '".$_GET["P"]."%'";
// echo $sql;die;//just to check query
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
  $resault = $conn->query($sql) or print_r($conn->error);  
  if ($resault->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<pre>";print_r($row);
  }
}
else{
    echo "no match found";

}
$conn->close();
}?>
```

Also are you have two `table` because you have two tables name after FROM in your query `node_revision` and `field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_` the second one looks half name of table. Also is `title` is present in both table or only in one you will also get `ambiguous` field `error` if both has `title